# aws-api-gateway-developer-portal deployment fails at StaticAssetUploader

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am trying to deploy AWS API Gateway Developer Portal using [serverless repo](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:563878140293:applications%7Eapi-gateway-dev-portal)

The Cloud formation fails and triggers rollback of the deployment. The error that causes the failure is as follows:

- Logical ID: **StaticAssetUploader**
- Status: **CREATE_FAILED**
- Reason: CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource. Please check your logs for requestId [ea5b3458-f29c-4950-b068-d0a3f352ad5f]. If you are using the Python cfn-response module, you may need to update your Lambda function code so that CloudFormation can attach the updated version.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you share the template and the code for the custom resource? It's not possible to say something useful otherwise.

Comment: Did you put your Lambda function artifact in S3 bucket properly?